# iPhone - Resuming background music after playing movie

Tags: iphone, video, background-music

I'm playing iTunes music in the background.
I started my app which plays "Video" using the following code:

```
NSString* videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"m4v"];
    if (player) {
        [player release];
        player = nil;
    }
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
    [self presentModalViewController:player animated:YES];
```

I'm setting the audio session as follows:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error:nil];
```

When my video starts playing, iPod music playing in the background will be stopped.
How can I resume the background music when my video completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of option to continue must from ipod is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Use notifications

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
      object:nil];

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish {
  // resume your AVAudioSession
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't read the description properly. I'm not asking how to continue playing music in my app. if itunes is playing the music, my app starts video. and when video completes in my app, itunes should continue.......